# Add Xcode build phase via CMake

Tags: xcode, cmake

I've tried searching for a solution to this issue but can't seem to find anything.

I need to add the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase using CMake. It can be added through Xcode itself as shown below:
[image]

But I need to do this via CMake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION.html). Here is an example:

```
file(GLOB XIB_FILES *.xib)
set_source_files_properties(${XIB_FILES} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
```

And don't forget to add ${XIB_FILES} to the list of your add_executable as in:

`add_executable(MyApp MACOSX_BUNDLE ${XIB_FILES} ...)`

Comment: Thanks Alf. Unfortunately I got configuration errors from CMake about `MACOSX_BUNDLE`. Could you elaborate a bit more about what that is?

Comment: I presume you are trying to create an iOS or an OSX app. MACOSX_BUNDLE is a property of add_executable which instructs cmake to create an application bundle. You can find more info [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html) and [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Bundles_And_Frameworks). The second link lists a number of variables you can use to customize the properties of your app bundle, which you can set like this:

set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "1.0")

Comment: My mistake. I had tried adding `MACOSX_BUNDLE` after this bit in my existing config `ADD_EXECUTABLE (${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_TYPE}`. Didn't realise `APP_TYPE` was already set to `MACOSX_BUNDLE`. Works now, after fine tweaking it to my project settings. For my situation, its just one .xcassets file that I want copied. Turns out doing `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RESOURCE Images.xcassets)` gives me the same result.

Comment: Does this only work for the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase type?  Is there a way to add a "Headers" phase?  I'd like to use Cmake to build an Xcode project for a shared library that needs to copy the public headers so that other Xcode projects gain access to them.  I've Googled everything I can think of to no avail.  Thanks for any help anyone can offer!